# Rider IDE error ".NET Framework Not Installed"

Tags: rider

I installed the newest Rider IDE from Jetbrains.
When I start it I always get this error:

> .NET Framework Not Installed: Download and install .NET Framework 4, .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Packs

However I installed 4.5.2 as you can see in the screenshot. What is going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have installed developer pack, not just .net runtime?

Comment: Yeah I downloaded the Developer Pack from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net452-developer-pack-offline-installer

Comment: In fact, .NET Framework 4/4.5 Developer Packs means .NET Framework SDK, which is now part of Windows SDK. Anyway, nobody bothers to make that explicit (Microsoft nor JetBrains), as you are supposed to target at least 4.5.2.

Comment: TargetFrameworkVersion in csproj should exactly match version of installed targets pack.